# StackOverflowException before I reach startup-method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a weird problem. I'm writing a quite large application in VB.NET / C# / WPF. But today, after I changed som XAML I can't run the application anymore. The only thing I get is a StackOverflowException right before the application is started - so my my logic tells me it's something about loading dll's and stuff.

Does anybody have an idea on what could cause problems like this? I really would give some more info on this problem, but I don't get any help from VS, because this happen before my code is actually started up.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 3.5

-- UPDATE 1 --
I don't get a stacktrace. All I get is a screen that says "Source Not Available. Source information is missing from the debug information for this module." and a StackOverflowException.

-- UPDATE 2 --
I can see that the exception happens in mscorlib, sounds really strange to me.

Comment: Can you specify "right before the application is started"?

Comment: Not quite. I can build my application just fine. When I try to run it in Debug mode, it stops after about 1-2 sec and throw the exception. I tried to put a breakpoint at the start of my "OnStartup" method - but it's never reached.

Comment: Why don't you show the code before and after the changes to see if anyone can work out if the change is the problem?

Comment: `"after I changed som XAML"` - Well, what did you change?  `"Does anybody have an idea on what could cause problems like this?"` - An infinite (or close enough to infinite) recursion.  Or a *very deep* call stack.

Comment: If you can run it under the debugger, you can see the stack trace when it crashes - which should tell you where the stack overflow is coming from.

Comment: Matthew, I cannot run it under the debugger, it crashes before it reach any real code. I don't get a stacktrace at all - that's why I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out what the problem is :/

Comment: Rollback today's changes in your local source control. Problem resolved.

Comment: Check if there are any errors logged in windows event tracing under application event category.

Comment: Check your .csproj file for the startup file, and try placing a breakpoint in the constructor of that class. I think it's the `ApplicationDefinition` tag. It sounds like the exception is occurring before the OnStartup method is hit

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. Sorry for taking up your time.

I made a infinite recursion in creating MergedDictionaries that referenced each other. Sorry guys!